# AdroidStudio 2.2.2 Empty Activity Error on phone

Tags: android-studio

I just started learning about Android development, so this one is a serious issue for me: I launch Android Studio (2.2.2, but had the issue since 2.2.1) on Win10, make a New project, just keep clicking Next without changing anything (selecting Empty Activity as the template), Finish, try to Run 'app' on my phone and consistently get this error:

> Error while executing: am start -n "com.example.android.myapplication/com.example.android.myapplication.MainActivity" -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] cmp=com.example.android.myapplication/.MainActivity }
>
> Error type 3
>
> Error: Activity class {com.example.android.myapplication/com.example.android.myapplication.MainActivity} does not exist.
>
> Error while Launching activity

Being a complete newbie who was just supposed to change some text in XML and run the app on a phone, I have no idea what to do or edit to make a pregenerated app actually work. I searched StackOverflow for a more general approach to these errors and tried:

- Restarting AS/computer
- Disabling InstantRun
- Messing with Clean/Rebuild/Synchronize/Sync with Gradle
- Deleting .gradle and .idea folders and Syncing with Gradle
- Some other obscure shenanigans with build.gradle and AndroidManifest
- Various combinations of the above.

... None of which worked (or affected the problem in any way, in fact).

Other observations:

- The app isn't even installed (checked All apps, there isn't any com.example.android.myapplication or MyApplication app on my device)
- On the development course forum, it was suggested that com.example.android.myapplication/com.example.android.myapplication.MainActivity should only read com.example.android.myapplication/MainActivity. So far I haven't been able to figure out how to change that.

**Update 1** New attempted fixes (neither of which worked):

- Specified activity directy in Run/Debug window.
- Specified no activity whatsoever (doesn't show that error, but doesn't run anything either).
- Did File/Invalidate Caches
- Changed android.intent.category.MAIN to all-lowercase and back.
- Added "category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/" to Manifest

**Update 2** Managed to run the app on emulator. It seems to be working there, so the error will likely be somewhere between AS and the phone (Android 5.1.1, API 22).

- Developer options and USB debugging are on (confirmed the pop-up message, too)
- Driver is up to date (AS can see the phone without problem)
- Phone is on (and not asleep) while I'm trying to run the app

Any suggestions why the phone won't download and run the app?

Answer (score 0):

In your manifest file edit 
    
 with android:name="com.example.android.myapplication.MainActivity"

Comment: I tried again, although it's something I've done before. Still doesn't work. Thanks for your reply, though!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your code doesn't mean any nonsense and that it wouldn't cause the app to crash, which is sometimes the problem. Try finding a problem in code which could crash the app. Maybe in your crash log you can find what causes the crash. Good luck fixing that.

Answer (score 0):

According with your error log I suppose you did not delete previously installed app. See [my accepted answer on the same question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47249317/753575) for details.